# Does this simple Haskell function already have a well-known name?

Tags: haskell, tuples, monads

I've just written this function which simply takes a pair whose second value is in some monad, and "pulls the monad out" to cover the whole pair.

```
unSndM :: Monad m => (a, m c) -> m (a, c)
unSndM (x, y) = do y' <- y
                   return (x, y')
```

Is there a nicer and/or shorter or point-free or even standard way to express this?

I've got as far as the following, with -XTupleSections turned on...

```
unSndM' :: Monad m => (a, m c) -> m (a, c)
unSndM' (x, y) = y >>= return . (x,)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Rules of tag `code-golf`: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info

Comment: Fair enough.  The site let me add the tag without telling me there were rules associated with it.  *shrug*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One minor point: it's possible to write this using only `fmap` (no `>>=`), so you really only need a `Functor` instance:

```
unSndM :: (Functor f) => (a, f c) -> f (a, c)
unSndM (x, y) = fmap ((,) x) y
```

This version is a bit more general. To answer your question about a pointfree version, we can just ask [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree):

```
travis@sidmouth% pointfree "unSndM (x, y) = fmap ((,) x) y"
unSndM = uncurry (fmap . (,))
```

So, yes, an even shorter version is possible, but I personally find `uncurry` a bit hard to read and avoid it in most cases.

If I were writing this function in my own code, I'd probably use `<$>` from `Control.Applicative`, which does shave off one character:

```
unSndM :: (Functor f) => (a, f c) -> f (a, c)
unSndM (x, y) = ((,) x) <$> y
```

`<$>` is just a synonym for `fmap`, and I like that it makes the fact that this is a kind of function application a little clearer.

Comment: The tupling also happens to be ordered conveniently, allowing a definition like `unSmdM = uncurry $ fmap . (,)`. Interestingly, the type of this function is much more readable/descriptive than either implementation :)

Comment: I agree, but `unSndM (x, y) = (x,) <$> y` is pretty close.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about pointfree - nice, thanks!  (I'd tried hoogle, of course.)  Some nice versions here, without any extra imports or modifications to libraries ;-) - thank you.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `pointfree`. I've been using `@pl` with lambdabot on #haskell the whole time.

Comment: I just love pointfree.  It should be part of every Haskell IDE.

Answer (score 13):

If the `Traversable` and `Foldable` instances for `(,) x)` were in the library (and I suppose I must take some blame for their absence)...

```
instance Traversable ((,) x) where
  traverse f (x, y) = (,) x <$> f y

instance Foldable ((,) x) where
  foldMap = foldMapDefault
```

...then this (sometimes called 'strength') would be a specialisation of `Data.Traversable.sequence`.

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

so

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => ((,) x) (m a) -> m (((,) x) a)
```

i.e.

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => (x, m a) -> m (x, a)
```

In fact, sequence doesn't really use the full power of `Monad`: `Applicative` will do. Moreover, in this case, pairing-with-x is linear, so the `traverse` does only `<$>` rather than other random combinations of `pure` and `<*>`, and (as has been pointed out elsewhere) you only need `m` to have functorial structure.

Comment: Sounds like the birth of a libraries@ proposal to me :-)

Comment: Nice, and costrength is also sequence! http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/src/Control-Functor-Strong.html

Comment: Astonishing stuff.  I knew it looked simple enough that a category theorist must have given it a name already.  :-)

Comment: It's not much of a simplification, but there is a 'sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)' defined in (Data.)Traversible . I figured that since you mentioned "you only need ... functorial structure", you could use it.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't seen it written in any Haskell library (though it's probably in category-extras), but it is generally known as the "tensorial strength" of a monad.  See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_monad

http://comonad.com/reader/2008/deriving-strength-from-laziness/

Answer (score 3):

Hoogle is your friend.  If one of the standard libraries had it then a hoogle for "[Monad m => (a, m b) -> m (a,b)](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a%2C+m+b%29+-%3E+m+%28a%2Cb%29)" would find it.  Note the function could still be in a [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html) package, but it often isn't worth an extra build-dep just for small functions like this.

Comment: "often isn't worth an extra build-dep just for small functions like this" <- this is such a sad thing :(